# Composer: prevent updating packages that require higher PHP version

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, composer-php

I'm using the `doctrine/dbal` (v2.4.*) package in my PHP project. My production server runs PHP v5.6.

I ran `composer update` this morning which updated my **composer.lock** file. Now, when I'm deploying to production, I see this:

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/common v2.4.3 requires doctrine/inflector 1.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
    - Installation request for doctrine/common v2.4.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[v2.4.3].
```

Specifically these:

> doctrine/common v2.4.3 requires doctrine/inflector 1.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
>
> doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version
>   (5.6.14) does not satisfy that requirement

This means, that even if `dbal` is old, it requires the newest `common`, and `common` requires the newest `inflector` package. Problem is that `inflector` started depending on PHP7 to run.

Is there any way in Composer to limit updating of the packages to those supported by specific PHP version? Like saying: "Please update what you can, but only if the server's PHP version is sufficient."

Comment: can you use inflector 1.1 instead? 
 
or go to common 2.7.3 
 
or you could go to dbal 2.5.13

Comment: You mean that I should require directly not only `doctrine/dbal` but also `common` and `inflector`? Does this make sense if `dbal` already requires them?

Comment: you can require dbal but just drop the version to 2.5.13

Comment: The `dbal` version I'm using is `2.4.*`. So, it's old. But as it requires newest packages internally, it doesn't matter how old it is.

Comment: try `composer require doctrine/inflector:1.1.0`

Comment: Your production environment setup is different from your development environment setup? And your development environment has newer version of software?

Comment: @Nima Actually, my dev environment uses PHP7, but the production server has not been upgraded yet. It wasn't a problem till today. However the issue will be solved, still would be nice to know if there's a solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `platform` option in your `composer.json` file to define the PHP version your production environment is using like this:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6.14"
        }
    }
}
```

see https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

Comment: *"Lets you **fake** platform packages (PHP and extensions) so that you can **emulate** a production env or define your target platform in the config"*. Sounds like something not exactly designed to be used on production. I guess I won't know for sure until I try.

Comment: As an alternative, run `composer require`, `composer update`, and `composer install` only in environments as close as possible to your production systems.

Comment: This answer is brilliant... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `composer.lock` file
- Run `composer install`